Serving a Subversion repository via HTTPS using Caddy instead of Apache?
I have been migrating various web thingies of mine to Caddy, and have been very pleased with it. At this point I have only one web thingy that's still using Apache -- read/write access to my Subversion repositories -- and I would like to migrate that too, so that I no longer have to run Apache at all.
Unfortunately, I have been unable to find anything to support this. I'm thinking it's possible that Subversion is (alas) so niche nowadays that it's just not on the radar for anyone who might have otherwise built a Caddy module for it, but I wanted to check here to see if I'm missing something.
A Subversion repository can be accessed directly on a file system via a file:// URL, and a standard part of the Subversion installation is a little server called svnserve which you can use to access to access the repository over the network via svn://. However, in most "real" cases, it's served via https:// instead, using Apache and the custom module mod_dav_svn (which in turn uses mod_dav to actually get at the repository).
My current plan is to set up reverse proxy from Caddy to Apache, but I am hoping for more direct Caddy-based solution (so that, like I said earlier, I can get rid of Apache entirely).
Please note that I already do have read-only access going through Caddy, via ViewVC. I'm specifically looking for read-write access.
Thanks in advance.
